# Vispy scene embedded into PyQt5 Application becomes black after being removed from layout then add back

Tags: pyqt5, vispy

The problem occurs after I do this series of operations:

1. Put two vispy.scene.SceneCanvas objects into two distinct QWidgets, call them scenewidget1, scenewidget2
2. Show a QWidget, add scenewidget1 and scenewidget2 to its layout
3. Remove scenewidget1 and scenewidget2 from layout, then add them back to layout
4. **One vispy SceneCanvas becomes black and shows nothing, it will recover after the user clicks the scene, is there any way to fix this problem?**

Before:

[image]

After remove from layout then add back:

[image]

Minimum Reproducible Example:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import vispy.scene as scene
from vispy.scene import visuals
import numpy as np

class SceneWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.scene = scene.SceneCanvas(parent=self, bgcolor='w')
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scene.native)
       
        # add something to the scene
        self.grid = self.scene.central_widget.add_grid(spacing=0)
        self.vb = self.grid.add_view(
            row=1, col=1, camera='panzoom', bgcolor=(1, 1, 1, 1), )
        self.scatter = visuals.Markers()
        self.vb.add(self.scatter)
        self.scatter.set_data(np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]))
        self.vb.camera.set_range(x=(-1, 3), y=(-1, 3))


class CentralWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.scenewidget1 = SceneWidget() # Scene Widget is a QWidget with a SceneCanvas at center
        self.scenewidget2 = SceneWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scenewidget1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scenewidget2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Remove From Layout Then Add Back')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.removeFromLayout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def removeFromLayout(self):
        self.layout.removeWidget(self.scenewidget1)
        self.layout.removeWidget(self.scenewidget2)
        self.scenewidget1.setParent(None)
        self.scenewidget2.setParent(None)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scenewidget1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scenewidget2, 0, 1, 1, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app = QApplication([])
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setCentralWidget(CentralWin())
    win.show()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(Qt.QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Layout changes (especially adding/removing widgets) and reparenting can cause various events, some of which are delayed and required for child widgets in order to properly react. What if you readd those widgets using a `QTimer.singleShot(someDelay, functionToReAddWidgets)`?

Comment: hello @musicamante thanks for your comment, but I am not sure where to use QTimer, would you please be more specific? I am new to Pyqt...

Comment: Create a function that does the last two `self.layout.addWidget` calls in removeFromLayout, and add that QTimer in place of them.

Comment: Try calling `.update()` on both Canvas objects (ex. `self.scenewidget1.scene.update()`) after re-adding them and see if that helps.

Comment: @djhoese thanks for your comment, but that does not work either...

Comment: So I tried your script and got the same results. Then I swapped out your custom widget and only used the `.scene.native` in the main window code. With that both of Canvases go black (possibly my fault). I'll have to try out some other ideas.

Comment: In case anyone finds this, this conversation has moved to https://github.com/vispy/vispy/issues/2270